# Does having blog and news on company's webpage come in pair?

Tags: blog

I've recently opened up small IT company which main tasks will be to administrate it infrastructure, outsourcing it, programming small applications (and release some of them for free, some to be bought), do some consulting, integrations. Basically everything IT company can do I'm going to do (on beginning alone, later on with employees).

So I've decided to have a webpage for my company but I can't decide on some little things in webdesign. I don't want to overload the page so I wanted the page to be good looking, functional and attractive to potential customers.

I was wondering then if Blog can or even should coexist with news page? Or should everything be done in form of Blog (news about new deal with client x, news about new program my company released, but also news on new Eset Smart Security being out and being offered by my company as reseller / consulting type). Also I am a bit techy so sometimes I would write about some administration issues / programming related things... or maybe I should skip it and never do that on company webpage? I would like this company site to evolve to something more then `just` another company's website... Or maybe it would be better to split those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do anything you want. Put everything in the blog, or have the blog be separate and have a "news" page. You'll find lots of examples of both and one isn't necessarily better then the other.

What matters most if whatever content you publish is well written and would be considered "quality content". If you are able to publish quality content in your website you will raise your visibility in the search engines which can be a great way to get targeted sales leads. Especially if you target "long tail" search phrases. Those leads tend the be *very* targeted.

The only stuff I would not include in your website, whether be it a blog or otherwise, is any content not related to what your company does. Having irrelevant content can only confuse potential customers about what services you offer and attract leads that are not potential customers. Publish that elsewhere but feel free to link to company website/blog whenever something semi-relevant does get published.

Comment: If my company is administering small companies (outsourcing it), implementing Windows, programming apps in C# and so on can I blog about related things? Like Windows 2008 R2 problem, new patch out, some coding solution? Or should I drop it?

Comment: If it ties into the services you offer in some way, and your examples would qualify as related, then blog about it. It helps to establish you as knowledgeable in your field and can bring in search traffic.